# Difficulty with proof of statement ( addition mod n)

Tags: number-theory

Proposition: Let $a,b,r\in \mathbb Z_n$ with n$>$2. Then, 
 $a+_nb =r$ (Which is remainder after a+b is divided by n) 
if and only if $\exists$ a $k \in \mathbb N$  such that  $a + b = kn +r $

I have to prove this, It seems really obvious from the definition of $+_n$ , So I do not know how to rigorously prove this.

(**Note:** I am unsure if Euclid's algorithm can be used in the proof as we have yet to cover that)

Comment: I'm not sure what the statement is. Maybe $a+_n b$ should equal $r$? Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Ludolila Thanks, Fixed

Comment: So what definition do you use? Is it: $a \equiv b \mod n $ iff $\exists k\in \mathbb Z$ s.t. $a=b+nk$? And $a+_n b = a+b \mod n$?

Comment: Have you covered that given two nonnegative integers $x,y$ there are unique integers $q,r$ with $x=qy+r$ and $0 \le r < y$? That's often covered before the full Euclid algorithm in texts, and can be used for your problem.

Comment: @Ludolila That's my issue with the question , rather vague . I know that $a+_n b$ = a+b mod n , but that has not been explicitly stated yet.

Comment: @coffeemath No, not yet. In detail I mean, but that can be assumed for now according to the text

Comment: So what can you use? What was explicitly stated?...

Comment: @Ludolila Nothing above is explicitly stated, However in another proof in that chapter they (the author) makes use of the fact that a mod n $ \Rightarrow a = bn +k$. This seems too easy..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly your question, you're just saying that $a+b$ and $r$ are in the same coset mod $n$. That is, 
$
a+b-r \equiv 0 $ mod $n$, which of course is equivalent to the existence of an integer $k$ such that $a+b-r=kn$.

Comment: They are , however we have not learn about cosets yet. I been reading ahead

Comment: Is a prove possible without Group Theory or use of equivalence classes